# Codename One - Custom Calendar day button

Tags: java, codenameone

My app saves appointments and shows them on a Multibutton list, but I also have created a screen with a Calendar using the GUI builder, because I want to create a "calendar view" so the user can take a look at the calendar and:

1- see every date that has at least one appointment highlighted (custom UIID)

2- see on each calendar day, the number of appointments he has for that day, along with the date of course.

I read I can do this by overriding `updateButtonDayDate()` and `createDay()` but I don't know how to do that in my code. Could you show me an example?

[image]

Comment: Felipe, I  have a similar issue with a CN1 application and would be interested in the code, in case you could find a solution. Could you post a snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you to override `updateButtonDayDate()` and `createDay()` in the Calendar class, you need to create a custom calendar that extends codenameone calendar (Make sure your extend `com.codename1.ui.calendar` and not `java.util`).

You will have to scrap GUI builder calendar and create one in code after creating your custom calendar class. Check the usage example that follows the code below:

```
import com.codename1.ui.Button;
import com.codename1.ui.Calendar;
import static com.codename1.ui.Component.CENTER;

public class CustomCalendar extends Calendar {

    @Override
    protected Button createDay() {
        //Customize your button here
        Button day = new Button();
        day.setAlignment(CENTER);
        day.setUIID("CalendarDay");
        day.setEndsWith3Points(false);
        day.setTickerEnabled(false);
        return day;
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateButtonDayDate(Button dayButton, int currentMonth, int day) {
        //Customize day values 
        dayButton.setText("" + day);
    }
}
```

And to use it, declare a new calendar based on your custom version:

```
CustomCalendar myCalendar = new CustomCalendar();
myContainer.add(myCalendar);
```

You can try all sort of things in your CustomCalendar until you find something that works. Ctrl + click on Calendar to check the source and know what you can override and what you can't.

You can even create your version of Calendar that extends Container (although not advisable).

Answer (score 0):

To select or display multiple dates in a Codename Calendar, one option is adding the dates to a list and format the date buttons according to the list items :

```
 cal = new Calendar() {

        @Override
        protected void updateButtonDayDate(Button dayButton, int currentYear, int currentMonth, int day  ) {

            list.add(1);
            list.add(12);
            list.add(13);
            list.add(14);
            list.add(21);


            for (int day_Number : list) {

                if (day_Number == day) {

                    dayButton.setText("" + day);
                    dayButton.setUIID("mycalender-day");

                }

        }

    };
```

The css file contains the formatting style:

```
mycalender-day {

border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
color:orange;
font-family:  "native:MainRegular";
font-size: 7pt;
}
```